# Best way to determine if frame is cross-domain?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

What is the best way to determine whether a frame is cross-domain? Here's what I have now:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#foo").load(function() {
        alert(isCrossDomain(window.frames["foo"]));
    });
});

function isCrossDomain(frame) {
    try {
        var test = frame.document.location.href;
        return false;
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="frame.html" id="foo" name="foo"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, the browser throws an exception when I try to access the frame's location.href property if it's cross-domain. But is it safe to rely on this behavior for all browsers? Is there a better way to implement the isCrossDomain function?

Thanks.

Comment: That's probably what I'd do, or something a lot like that.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just get the `src` attribute of the IFRAME and check if protocol, port and host are different?

Comment: The src attribute doesn't change when the iframe location changes. And, no, you can't access that information when it's cross-domain.